# Both os.path.isfile(fullpath) and os.path.isdir(fullpath) return false ! Why?

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

Traversing the directory and all subdirectories (Windows 8.1) mentioned below to print all files with their full paths returns an error (invalid directory).
When testing in the python interpreter I get the following outputs:

```
os.path.isfile("C:\\Miele_Service\\Miele Offline-ETD\\DATA_data.mdf")
```

Gives:

```
False
```

Also:

```
os.path.isdir("C:\\Miele_Service\\Miele Offline-ETD\\DATA_data.mdf")
```

Gives:

```
False
```

It seems to me that there is a problem with permissions as *.mdf is an sql database file.

What do I need to do to gain necessary permissions through the code to be able to confirm that it indeed is a file and print it out?

---

Edit:

Results of checking with icacls function in command prompt:

for the directory where the access denied files are:

```
> icacls "C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD"
C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD 

    Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

for the file which I get access denied error (I had to use a different file than in the opening post as I changed manually permissions for the original file to confirm it is a read access permission problem):

```
> icacls "C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD\DATA_log.ldf"
C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD\DATA_log.ldf: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

What is the module I should use to modify permissions to files and directories automatically in Python?

edit 2:

Checks in elevated command prompt:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>icacls "C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD"
C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD 

    Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
    BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
    NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\Windows\system32>icacls "C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD\DATA_log.ldf"
C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD\DATA_log.ldf 

    TKlucziowski\SQLServerMSSQLUser$TKlucziowski$MIELE_ETD:(F)
    OWNER RIGHTS:(F)
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

It appears that with the Administrator rights icacls is able to access the file successfully...

So please point me at a module which enables permissions rights changes in Python. I'm new to this but I understand that the best approach is to temporarily remove the restriction (and back it up somehow?) and after accessing the file restore the previous permissions.

Thx.

Comment: It returns access denied when trying to open it....

Comment: It returns access denied when trying to open it.... Just changed the owner of it and I can access it now so the file exists, but still python returns invalid directory. Does os.listdir(path) function have an issue with directories containing SPACE character in their name?

Comment: I have no issue accessing the file in windows and windows reads the directory without any problems...

Comment: oK just confirmed. I had to change the permissions for Administrators and Owners to get full access to the file (it was still showing access denided after changing it only for the Administrators. After that python function isfile returns True but now some other files in the same directory have similar protection enabled and cause the same issue (invalid directory. Suppose I have a directory full of files protected like that and I do not want to manually edit all the file permissions in Windows what module enables that function in python please?

Comment: Ok, this is a permissions problem. Edit your question to include the output of `icacls "C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD"` for the directory and also for one of the files that you can't access.

Comment: You shouldn't need full access, by the way, only read access.  Specifically `FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES`.  And in most cases you can just change the permission on the parent directory and let the change be inherited by the directory tree.

Comment: that's exactly what my original supposition was...

Comment: You can distinguish between files and directories, without needing permission on the individual files, by listing the contents of the parent directory.  Not sure how/whether you can do that in Python.  It is also likely that `.isfile` and `.isdir` would work as desired if you first enabled backup and restore privilege, @eryksun, is that possible in Python?

Comment: Did you run icacls from an elevated command prompt? If not try checking the file security again in an elevated command prompt. I want to see what's there before making any suggestions to modify it.

Comment: The file has had explicit permissions (rather than inherited permissions) set, presumably by the database software, presumably for a reason.  Changing the permissions and then changing them back again isn't a good solution.  Your program shouldn't mess with another program's files.  It wouldn't work anyway; if you aren't running elevated, you won't have permission to change the permissions, and if you 
*are* running elevated you won't *need* to change the permissions.  Either list the contents of the parent directory somehow, or run the program with elevated privilege.

Comment: Thx :) I will check how to do it.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `os.path.isfile("C:\\Miele_Service\\Miele Offline-ETD\\DATA_data.mdf")` would return `False`. It's implemented via `os.stat`, which falls back on the data from listing the parent directory via `FindFirstFile`, and you have the right to list the parent directory. Try `os.stat("C:\\Miele_Service\\Miele Offline-ETD\\DATA_data.mdf")`.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong, Python cannot find your file.

Add a `\` before the space in your path to escape it.

Anyway, this should not be a permission issue.

Comment: Where exactly do you see a single `\` in the OP's code?

Comment: It seems he edited his question, the code is different from what I first saw.

Comment: It was formatted incorrectly, apparently SO text editor requires double `\\` in non-code text blocks.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
os.path.isdir("C:\\Miele_Service\\Miele\ Offline-ETD\\DATA_data.mdf")
```

you have a space character in the dir name

Most of interpreters treat a space character as end, therefore, in the considered case os.path.isdir looks for `C:\Miele_Service\Miele` dir instead of `C:\Miele_Service\Miele Offline-ETD`, can't find it, returns `False`.
`\` is used to include the space character into the name/path (treat as a symbol, no special meaning)

Comment: Space characters have no special meaning in this string literal; don't need to be escaped; and this is just inserting a backslash character in the string where none belongs. You appear to be confusing how paths are used in a shell, in which space is an argument delimiter, versus paths as string literals in a Python script.

Comment: There is an actual space in the directory name: os.path.isfile("C:\\Miele_Service\\Miele Offline-ETD\\DATA_data.mdf") Just checked, its there. The name of the directory before the file is "Miele Offline-ETD". It contains a space. There are no missing \\.

Comment: Ok it has nothing to do with the space. Just checked. Space has no special meaning in the path and can be contained in the directory name. All the subdirectories are split with \\ so there is no problem here. The problem is that both checks isfile and isdir return False and my program then tries to use the path as a directory (but it is a file) and fails. Why does it return False for both checks ???